# How does this reverse-engineered algorithm work?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, reverse-engineering, algebra, simplify

The actual algorithm function is:

```
output[i] = ( (129 * input[i]) XOR input[i-1]) % 256 //input[-1] = 0
```

There are several solutions to this. The one that is usually done is along the lines of:

```
var output = [0, 129, 3, 129, 7, 129, 3, 129, 15, 129, 3, 129, 7, 129, 3, 129];
var outputToInputArray = function(array) {
  var input = [];
  var outputToInput = function(dig, lastInput) {
    var current = dig;

    while(true) {
      if (!((current ^ lastInput) % 129)) {
        return (current ^ lastInput)/129;
      }
      current += 256;
    }
  }

  for(var i = 0; i < output.length; i++) {
    input.push(outputToInput(output[i], i>0 ? input[i-1] : 0));
  }

  return input;
}

console.log(outputToInputArray(output));
```

However, I just came accorss:

```
output = [0, 129, 3, 129, 7, 129, 3, 129, 15, 129, 3, 129, 7, 129, 3, 129]
var input = [];
for(var i =0; i < output.length; i++) {
    lastInput = input.length < 1 ? 0 : input[i-1];
    input.push(((output[i] ^ lastInput) * 129) % 256);
}
console.log(input);
```

The idea to follow when asked to reverse a function is to algebraically reverse the function.  However, the second solution seems to simplify the reversed function in a way that should not be mathematically valid! But it works! Please help!

P.S. Expected output is [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]

Comment: you can't reverse a hash. they're one-way functions. the specific computations done in a proper hash cannot be reversed to get the original value(s) that produced the hash. e.g. `1+2 => 3` is fine, but `3 -> ???`. there's a literal infinity of possibilities: `sqrt(9)`, `4-1`, etc...

Comment: I hear what you're saying but this is a special case where the hash function is reverse-engineerable.

Comment: @MarcB most hash functions are one-way (or close; the existence of truly one-way functions is an open question in CS). One could make a hash function that, for a given domain of inputs, is reversable.

Comment: True enough, guess I should start thinking more generally and not just "cryptographic hash".

Comment: Although it seems like the output of this "hash function" isn't just a single value of a fixed number of bits... it looks like it's the same size as the input. So it's not really a hash

Comment: Fine it's not a hash... removed 'hash' tag, changed language and variable names

Comment: Whoops, well my answer addresses the hash part

Comment: Have a look at [this page](https://naml.us/blog/2012/03/inverse-of-a-hash-function), which mentions [Feistel cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feistel_cipher). I haven't understood how that works, but that should give you the right direction. There is also similar example [here](https://gist.github.com/lh3/974ced188be2f90422cc), which might help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Note: after writing up this answer, I re-read the answer by qxz, and
>   realized that everything covered here is also covered in qxz's answer.
>   But I've decided to post this anyways, since a slightly different
>   format may be helpful to some.

To understand why this works, all you have to do is compute

```
y = (129 * x) % 256;
```

for each x between 0 and 255. Start with the even numbers

```
for ( x = 0; x < 256; x += 2 ) {
    y = (129 * x) % 256; 
    console.log(y);
}
```

The output is

```
  0   0
  2   2
  4   4
  6   6
  8   8
 10  10
 12  12
 14  14
... ...
```

In other words, even numbers aren't changed when you multiple by 129 modulo 256.

The output for the odd numbers is

```
  1 129
  3 131
  5 133
  7 135
  9 137
 11 139
... ...
125 253
127 255
129   1
131   3
133   5
... ...
```

In other words, multiplying by 129 modulo 256 is the same as adding 128 to the number modulo 256. So when you do it twice you get the original number back: `(x + 128 + 128) % 256 = x`

The rest of the formula really doesn't have any effect on this. Modulo 256 drops any bits above bit 7, keeping the lower 8 bits. The XOR has no effect on the bits above bit 7, it simply inverts some of the lower 8 bits. Thus there's no interaction between the XOR and the modulo 256. The XOR only affects the lower 8 bits, and the modulo only affects the upper bits.

Which means that when reversing the calculation, you can do the XOR first to get the lower 8 bits back. And then multiplying by 129 modulo 256 either does nothing (if the number is even) or it adds 128 modulo 256 (if the number is odd). Either way, you get the original number back.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, your "hash function" isn't really a hash function in the traditional sense. A hash function usually takes an input (which could be of variable size, such as a string) and transforms it into a single value of a fixed number of bits. This type of function cannot really be reversed, because many bits of data are lost in the conversion; you can't reconstruct 100 bits from 4 bits.

Your function transforms a list of bytes into another equal-length list of bytes. It looks like it takes the current input, runs it through the function `x => (x*129)%256`, and then `xor`s it with the previous input.

The function `f(x) = (x*129) % 256` is the interesting part. If the input is even, the output is the same number. If the input is odd, the output is the input with bit 7 (the 127ths place) inverted. (Try plugging in a few values yourself.) Thus, `f(x)` is it's own inverse; `f(f(x)) == x`.

Therefore, the whole "hash function" can be inverted like so:

- `xor` the current hash value with the previous input value, or `0` if the first one
- run the result through the `f(x)` function to invert the `f(x)` when the value was calculated
- repeat for each value

... which is what that last snippet of yours does. I'm not sure about the first one.

Comment: x*129 = x<<7 + x, which is equivalent to x<<7 ^ x when you consider the modulo overflow

Comment: My function is not  x => (x*129)%256 it is x=> ((129 * x) XOR x[i-1]) % 256.

As far as I know the modulus cannot be distributed between (129 * x) and x[i-1] because XOR does not have a distributive property. so you can't single out (x*129) % 256

Comment: @samgak 255*129= (255<<7)+255 = 32895 != (255<<7)^255 which is 32639

Comment: @googamanga it can if you rewrite the % 256 as & 255: ((129 * x) ^ x[i-1]) & 255 => ((129 * x) & 255) ^ (x[i-1] & 255)

Comment: 32895 & 255 = 32639 & 255 = 127